# What is the closest equivalent of an elliptic Gaussian distribution on the hypersphere?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, spherical-geometry

The van Mises Fisher (vMF) distribution ($p(x;\mu,\kappa) \propto e^{-\kappa\mu^\top x}$ can be considered a close equivalent of a symmetric Normal Distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \mathbf{I})$ on the hypersphere. "Close" here means that the vMF distribution is spherically symmetric, has a similar bell-shape as the Gaussian distribution and is relatively easy to work with.

What is the closest equivalent of an axis-aligned elliptical Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ (with diagonal covariance $\Sigma$) on a hypersphere?

I first thought it might be something like $p(z;\mu,\Sigma)\propto e^{z^\top\Sigma\mu}$ (as the direct extension of a vMF distribution), but that's equivalent to a standard vMF with a shifted mean $\Sigma\mu/\left\|\Sigma\mu\right\|$.

Comment: As far as I can tell an [elliptical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution) Gaussian distribution *is* one whose covariance matrix *is not* the identity. The closest equivalent therefore *is* that distribution itself. Why hypersphere and not ellipsoid?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. Sure, the covariance matrix should not be the identity. But the space I am considering is a hypersphere, so I cannot use a standard Gaussian distribution but search for the closest equivalent of it.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what the v$\color{red}{o}$n Mises Fisher distribution exactly is and why that is the closest (in what sense?) equivalent to a symmetric normal distribution . This would provide more context and make the question better understandable.

Comment: Good point, I tried to clarify my intent!

Comment: Perhaps [arxiv.org/abs/2103.07948](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.07948) helps.